# Filter emails in a support shared mailbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, flow

I want to use a **support shared mailbox** to receive customer complaints in a company. 
When I receive an email in the shared mailbox, **a flow is automatically executed**.

How to make sure to execute the flow **only** when it is a question of customer reclosure, knowing that the support address can be used for something else (*email exchanges...*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice I have found is to create an alias "open-ticket" to the shared mailbox, and use a rule that makes a condition on header mail: **if it contains that alias then move the received mail to Tickets folder for example**. That's works for me and allows me to filter mails on my shared mailbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **Flow Trigger Conditions**.

Go to settings for your trigger and apply the trigger condition that helps you reduce the number of times the flow is triggered.

For example, This is my trigger condition for only triggering for access request emails - @contains(toUpper(triggerBody()?['subject']),'WANTS TO ACCESS')

[image]

Comment: Actually, trigger conditions are not available for **When a new mail arrives in a shared mailbox** trigger.

Comment: They are available above screenshot is settings page of that

Comment: The settings page of **When a new mail arrives in shared mailbox (V2)** trigger does not contain trigger conditions and there is no V3.

Comment: Maybe it will be available to you soon if Microsoft is releasing this in stages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the email properties to identify “a question of customer reclosure”.

For example, the emails contain specific strings in the subject.

In that case, you can set rules for the incoming emails directly in Outlook, then trigger the flow when emails arrive in a specific folder.

Or you can trigger a flow directly based on the subject itself.

Please see the references below.

[Trigger a flow based on email properties.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/email-triggers)

[Manage email messages by using rules.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59)

Comment: What I am trying to do is put a condition on object inside the flow since trigger conditions are not available for **When an email arrives in a shared mailbox**. Otherwise, is there anything to do with **email alias** ?